# Build an array from an API loop using Vue and AXIOS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a NIH API that can call only 50 pages at a time.  The code below works for the first page of 50 items.

```
loadNIH() {
      let offset = 0;
      axios({
        method: "GET",
        url:
          "https://api.federalreporter.nih.gov/v1/projects/search?query=orgName:Medical University of South Carolina$fy:2016$&offset=" + offset +"&limit=50"
      })
        .then(res => {
          this.NIHData = res.data.items;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

I need to loop all of the pages until I get all of the data.  Each time the offset needs to increase by the number of pages received (requested 50) 9 pages in this call.  I need it to ADD data to the array of this.NIHData.  I got one working so I need some help creating the loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you just move the `offset` out of your function, use `offset += 50` inside the function, and call `loadNIH()` from inside the success path? (Until a condition is met)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem is how many times to call it?  The answer is on the first result set and you don't know when to quit until the last one.The number 9 changes based upon the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should repeatedly call the API until you get an empty resultset. This can be most easily achieved with the help of `setTimeout()`

```
loadNIH() {
  let params =
  {
    offset: 0
  }
  this.NIHData = [];
  this.fetchPages(params);
},
fetchPages(args)
{
  axios.get("https://api.federalreporter.nih.gov/v1/projects/search?query=orgName:Medical University of South Carolina$fy:2016$&offset=" + args.offset +"&limit=50"
  )
    .then(res => {
      this.NIHData.push(res.data.items);
      args.offset += res.data.items.length;
      if (res.data.items.length > 0) setTimeout(this.fetchPages, 2);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Works great up until the this.fetchPages from fetchPages then axios throws an error saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined

Comment: Added setTimeout(this.fetchPages(args), 2); and it loops great, but now I get an error at  this.NIHData.push(res.data.items); of Cannot read property 'NIHData' of undefined"

Comment: but if I change it to this.NIHData = res.data.items; I see the data load each page until the null response.

Comment: but  this.NIHData = this.NIHData.concat(res.data.items); worked fine